# Change the sudo su shell

Tags: macos, zsh, sudo, sh, oh-my-zsh

Whenever I run `sudo su` from my normal `zsh` (which uses the [oh-my-zsh](https://r.duckduckgo.com/l/?kh=-1&uddg=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Frobbyrussell%2Foh-my-zsh) framework), I'm forced to use the old Bourne shell (`sh`) by default (obviously; this is standard behaviour on most *nix-like systems). If I run `zsh` from within `sh` after running `sudo su`, I get the Z shell, but without the improvements from oh-my-zsh.

Is there any way to change the shell `sudo su` launches to `zsh`? If so, is it possible to also have that instance of `zsh` launch using `oh-my-zsh`?

I'm using OS X 10.8.4.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Another way to execute an interactive shell as the superuser is `sudo -s`, which uses `$SHELL` as the shell.

As the comments in the other answer mentioned, `su -s /path/to/zsh` doesn't work in OS X.

OS X doesn't support changing login shells in `/etc/passwd` either, but you can use `dscl`:

```
$ dscl . -read /Users/root UserShell
/bin/sh
$ sudo dscl . -change /Users/root UserShell /bin/sh /bin/zsh
$ dscl . -read /Users/root UserShell
/bin/zsh
$ sudo su
My-iMac# echo $0
zsh
My-iMac# exit
$ sudo dscl . -change /Users/root UserShell /bin/zsh /bin/sh
$
```

`/bin/sh` is not a Bourne shell anymore on most platforms. It is a [POSIX-compliant version of bash](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/89311/are-bash-bourne-and-korn-shells-compiled-into-one-binary-in-osx/89327#89327) in OS X and dash in Ubuntu.

Comment: This is what I would think the question wanted. It's definitely what worked for me; thank you so much! *edit* i see what he wanted now - I don't think this is what he wanted, so I can't fairly upvote it for this question, but I think you deserve a medal anyway. You had the answer to _my_ question!

Answer (score 5):

From the `su` manpage, there are two ways you can accomplish this.

---

The first method is to simply use the `-s` or `--shell` flag (assuming you are using a *NIX-based OS with a version of `su` that supports this argument), followed by the path to the shell of your choice.  If the passed shell cannot be found, `su` reverts to the following method, and failing that, will attempt to invoke `/bin/sh`.

For example, you can force `su` to launch `zsh` (assuming it exists in `/bin/zsh`) as:

```
sudo su --shell /bin/zsh
```

---

The second method is to modify the default shell specified for the `root` user (**be careful!**).  This can be done by editing the file `/etc/passwd` and changing the shell specified for the `root` user.  To see what shell is specified by default, you can run the following command (assuming the superuser is root):

```
sudo grep root /etc/passwd
```

The command should output something like `root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash`.  You can simply change the `/bin/bash` (or whatever is set in your system) to point to `zsh` instead.

Comment: As always, be careful about changing root's shell. You don't want to be in single user mode, and have a root shell that needs /usr when it's broken. At lease make sure your new shell has no more filesystem dependencies than the one you're replacing

Comment: Running `sudo su -s /bin/zsh` (or using `--shell`) returns `su: illegal option -- s`. I'm on OS X 10.8.4; does OS X take a different command?

Comment: @JulesMazur what is the output of `cat /etc/shells`?  Technically only shells allowed in that file will be launched, although the `su` manpage says this shouldn't matter if `su` is called by root :S

Comment: `cat /etc/shells` returns `/bin/zsh` as an acceptable shell.

Comment: @JulesMazur ah, sorry - I just saw the [su manpage](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/su.1.html) from Apple's site (I don't own any Apple products, I'm running Linux) doesn't specify the `-s` option...  However, you may have some luck experimenting with the environment switches (e.g. `-m`) after setting your `$SHELL` variable.

Comment: @JulesMazur please remember to always include your OS to avoid this kind of confusion.

Comment: I've updated `/etc/passwd` to use `zsh`, and running `sudo cat /etc/passwd | grep root` returns `root:*:0:0:System Administrator:/var/root:/bin/zsh`, but running `sudo su` still goes to `sh`.

@terdon will do.

Comment: @JulesMazur sorry, after looking at Apple's `su` manpage, I don't think changing that will do anything.  The manpage itself doesn't specify any additional information as to how to specify a default shell (outside of setting the `$SHELL` env. variable).  As a workaround, you might just want to do `sudo /bin/zsh` to launch a `zsh` shell as root.

Comment: I got it working using a disgusting, contorted (but crucially, loop-avoiding) shell script. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Can be easily done with `chpass`:

```
$ sudo chpass -s /bin/zsh
```

Answer (score 1):

A cleaner way that will also protect your system in case your custom shell is blown up is to create a .profile in root's home directory w/:

```
if [ -x /opt/local/bin/bash ]; then
    SHELL=/opt/local/bin/bash
    export SHELL
    exec /opt/local/bin/bash
else
    echo /opt/local/bin/bash not found using default shell of $SHELL
fi
```

Just change the path to the shell you want instead of bash.